# API.AI: how to call the same intent repeatedly

Tags: dialogflow-es

In API.AI, I have created CheckQuality intent to check the air quality as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lduMx.png).

Included 2 parameters 'city' and 'date'.
1. I have declared 'date' (as entity @sys.date ) with default value of Today .
2. I have marked 'date' as required.

Two questions defined:

1. How is the air quality in Boston?
2. How about Tomorrow?

I have declared context name cq(brown color box) in output context so i don't have to mention city again and again if user asks for some other day.

Query in Order
1. how is the air quality in Boston Today ?
2. how about tomorrow ?

Practically:

Question 1 doesn't initialize geo-city(marked in red color) but initialize date and ask for location and that's why context is also not created.

Expected:

Question 1 will initialize geo-city as Boston, date as Today and create a context.
Question 2: geo-city we can fetch from cq context and date form user as it will be Tomorrow for 2nd Question.

Question : **So i just want the way, how to intialize geo-city with Question 1**

**Required**

1. I do not want to create any other intent.

note : in magenta color box i changed the value of geo-city .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43146087/how-to-expire-context-lifespan-on-specific-user-input-api-ai

Answer (score 0):

i just saw the image you have clipped.
also you have made a note that you changed the value from $geo-city to #cq.geo-city.
That is where you are going wrong i think, you must use #cq.geo-city in your next intent which will have the IN-context as "cq" and it will answer the question "What about tomorow?"
In this intent keep the value as $geo-city itself, or you wont be able to capture the parameter value here.
I may be wrong but most probably right, make a try if you still havent found a solution to this.