# How to expire context lifespan on specific user input - api.ai

Tags: javascript, artificial-intelligence, bots, chatbot, dialogflow-es

i'm working with api.ai and stuck on a point
i want to expire lifespan of a context on a specific user input

how to expire context lifespan on specific user input Api.ai

any one please tell me solution since i'm unable to find it in documentation of api.ai

Answer (score 0):

You can "reset" the context by setting the output context's lifetime to 0 as described on this page: https://docs.api.ai/docs/concept-contexts

[image]